# What IPv4 network is better for serial?

Tags: routing, ipv4, ip, subnet, internet

I've been looking for some examples to configure a subnet, and I've seen that, for example, when you have this IPv4 network for the hosts `192.168.0.0/24`, people use this IPv4 network for the serial: `10.0.0.0/30`. So, why do they do that? Wouldn't be better to just use the same IPv4 range `192.168.X.0/30`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter. There is no better IP address range for any type of interface. It may be that examples use the `10.0.0.0/30` network because it is easy to see that it is different and clear that it is a different use.

The old-school way of doing point-to-point links was with `/30` networks, but that wastes half of the addresses in a network. About 16 years ago, [RFC 3021, Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021) was released to specifically allow `/31` networks for point-to-point links. Some hardware manufacturers never adopted the RFC, and none of the carriers of which I know did.